# Trying to plot simple histogram in ggplot2 gives "Error: position_stack requires constant width"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why is this happening? And how do I work around this?

```
> qplot(c(0,0,0,0,1e12))
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Error: position_stack requires constant width
> qplot(c(0,0,0,0,1e12), binwidth=1e12/30)
Error: position_stack requires constant width
> qplot(c(0,0,0,0,1e12), binwidth=1e10)  # works
> qplot(c(0,0,0,0,1e12), binwidth=1e11)  # works
```

I found http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/ggplot2-histograms-a-subtle-error-found-td2305814.html but in their case the problem was that the binwidth is much smaller than the values. Here, they are on similar orders of magnitude.

Comment: That's curious. You may be more interested in the why, but setting `position = "identity"` seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that this is a numerical precision problem. A little sleuthing with `traceback` and `debug` reveals that the problem occurs in this check in the function `collide`:

```
if (check.width && length(widths) > 1 && sd(widths) > 1e-06) {
            stop(name, " requires constant width", call. = FALSE)
}
```

The widths are just different enough for the sd to be too big. The fact that this problem disappears with smaller values further seems like evidence for a numerical precision issue.

But the values used to generate the widths don't originate in `collide`, so the real problem is probably caused further upstream, though I'm not familiar enough with the innards of `ggplot` to speculate further.